# Prepaying interest with set installment amount where extra payment is applied to principal

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

I believe this is a problem of computing the limit of a recursive sequence.

Let's say I have a mortgage of \$332950 and a 6% annual interest rate. The mortgage contract requires that interest for each year is prepaid for each year on Dec 31 in the amount of \$20,000. (Interest for 2016 is paid on Dec 31 2015) Any amount paid above the required interest is applied to the principal. Now, 6% of \$332950 is \$19977, NOT \$20000, so by default the contract requires paying more than just interest, and so some of that money will be applied to the principal.

The problem is that if \$23 of the $20000 installment is applied to principal, then the the interest due is thereby decreased. If the interest due is decreased, then even more is applied to principal. I ran a 100 iterations of this cycle using a `python` script, and after 10 iterations, the amount applied to interest reaches a limit of \$24.4680851064. How can I compute this limit without using brute force?

If I understand the notation correctly, this is how to define the sequence:

> Suppose $a_0 = 0$, and
>   $$ a_n = 20000 - ( ( 332950 - a_{n-1}) \cdot 0.06)$$
>   if $n \ge 1$.

How do I compute the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

```
iteration   a
0           0
1           23
2           24.38
3           24.4628
4           24.467768
5           24.46806608
6           24.46808396
7           24.46808504
8           24.4680851
9           24.46808511
10          24.46808511
...         ...
100,000,000 24.46808511
```

Comment: If $lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=L$ then $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_{n-1}=L$.

Comment: Replace bothv$ a_n $ and $a_{n-1}$ by $L $ and solve. you will find tge limit L.

Comment: The value $24,46...$ you got is not the limit. to reach the limit you need more iterations.

Comment: @SalahFatima But it doesn't make sense that the limit would be lower than $23 (the original amount applied to principal), since I assume it should be monotonic (only grow).

Comment: After 100,000,000 iterations, python gives me 24.4680851064 (same as 10 iterations). This may be a limitation of python's `float` data type, but I still believe the function is monotonic. I also implemented my sequence in a spreadsheet and got the same solution, so I am confident that the sequence is defined correctly.

Comment: You made a mistake. it is $+0.06L$ not $-$

Comment: Oops. How embarrassing! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SalahFatima for the comments. If I replace $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ with $L$, then I have the following solution:

> $$ a_n = 20000 - ( ( 332950 - a_{n-1}) \cdot 0.06)$$
>   $$ L = 20000 - ( ( 332950 - L) \cdot 0.06)$$
>   $$ L = 20000 - 19977 + 0.06L$$
>   $$ L = 23 + 0.06L$$
>   $$ 0.94L = 23$$
>   $$ L = \frac{23}{0.94}$$
>   $$ L = 24.4680851 $$